# How to kill someone standing on a certain block

Tags: minecraft-commands

So I am building a minecraft parkour. In a certain level, people may not walk on the red wool. When they walk on it, they die.

Can someone help with the code on my command block ?

I have this right now :

```
/execute @a [XYZ] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:wool 14 kill @p
```

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/execute @a[r=radius] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:wool 14 kill @a[c=1]
```

This should work..

- Put the command block in the center of that area and use a radius covering it, so people don't die where they shouldn't.
- Use `@a[c=1]` instead of `@p`, because someone else walking by could die when there's still someone who died and hasn't respawned.
- As proposed in the comments the selector `@s` can as well be used instead of `@a[c=1]` (assuming you're on 1.12). This will target the entity that is executing the command.

Comment: assuming it's in 1.12 you should use `@s` instead if `@a[c=1]` anyways.
also, using regional selectors is a thing and probably what they were trying to do: `@a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,dx=DX,dy=DY,dz=DZ]`

Comment: good point @Plagiatus